# Input Menu Screen Method always Returns 0

Tags: java, function, return

I was assigned to create a menu driven program which contained a function that showed the menu screen/get the user input, but `displaymenu()` always and only returns 0 instead of the new inputted number.

I'm pretty new to programming and I've googled everything I can think of and I'm pretty stuck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class menuDriven
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int menuSelection=0;
      double inches, centimeters, feet, meters, miles, kilometers;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      displayMenu(keyboard, menuSelection);


      switch(menuSelection)
      {
      case 1:
         inchesToCentimeters(keyboard);
         break;

      case 2:
         feetToMeters(keyboard);
         break;

      case 3:
         milesToKilometers(keyboard);
         break;
      }

   } // end main

   public static int displayMenu(Scanner keyboard,  int menuSelection) 
   {

   System.out.println("1. Convert inches to centimeters");
   System.out.println("2. Convert feet to meters");
   System.out.println("3. Convert miles to kilometers");
   System.out.println();

   System.out.println("Enter your selection");
   menuSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (menuSelection < 1 || menuSelection > 3)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
         menuSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
      }
   return menuSelection;
   }

   public static void inchesToCentimeters(Scanner keyboard)
   {
      double inches, centimeters;
      System.out.print("Enter the number of inches: ");
      inches = keyboard.nextDouble();
      centimeters = inches * 2.54;
      System.out.println("That is equal to " + centimeters + " 
centimeters.");

   }

   public static void feetToMeters(Scanner keyboard)
   {
      double feet, meters;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of feet: ");
      feet = keyboard.nextDouble();
      meters = feet * 0.3048;
      System.out.println("That is equal to " + meters + " meters.");
   }

   public static void milesToKilometers(Scanner keyboard)
   {
      double miles, kilometers;
      System.out.println("Enter the number of miles: ");
      miles = keyboard.nextDouble();
      kilometers = miles * 1.609;
      System.out.println("That is equal to " + kilometers + " 
kilometers.");
   }
} // end class
```

The program should take the user input 1, 2, or 3 and then take that number to the switch and display the code.

Comment: because you need to add  menuSelection=keyboard.nextInt();  after your displayMenu(keyboard, menuSelection);

Comment: @LiamWilson Wouldn't that render `displayMenu` redundant & allow an invalid value to be entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java passes primitive arguments by value, so although you manipulate the `menuSelection` parameter in `displayMenu`, `menuSelection` in `main` stays the same as it does before calling `displayMenu`.

You could assign the result of `displayMenu` to `menuSelection`:

```
menuSelection = displayMenu(keyboard, menuSelection);
```

You can also remove the passing of `menuSelection` as a parameter & have it declared inside `displayMenu`, eg:

```
public static int displayMenu(Scanner keyboard) {
    int menuSelection=0;

    //...
}
```

Comment: This worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class menuDriven{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    displayMenu(keyboard);

} // end main

private static void displayMenu(Scanner keyboard)
{

    System.out.println("1. Convert inches to centimeters");
    System.out.println("2. Convert feet to meters");
    System.out.println("3. Convert miles to kilometers");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter your selection");
    int menuSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (menuSelection < 1 || menuSelection > 3)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1, 2, or 3.");
        menuSelection = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    switch(menuSelection)
    {
        case 1:
            inchesToCentimeters(keyboard);
            break;

        case 2:
            feetToMeters(keyboard);
            break;

        case 3:
            milesToKilometers(keyboard);
            break;
    }
    /* return menuSelection; */
}

private static void inchesToCentimeters(Scanner keyboard)
{
    double inches, centimeters;
    System.out.print("Enter the number of inches: ");
    inches = keyboard.nextDouble();
    centimeters = inches * 2.54;
    System.out.println("That is equal to " + centimeters + " centimeters.");

}

private static void feetToMeters(Scanner keyboard)
{
    double feet, meters;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of feet: ");
    feet = keyboard.nextDouble();
    meters = feet * 0.3048;
    System.out.println("That is equal to " + meters + " meters.");
}

private static void milesToKilometers(Scanner keyboard)
{
    double miles, kilometers;
    System.out.println("Enter the number of miles: ");
    miles = keyboard.nextDouble();
    kilometers = miles * 1.609;
    System.out.println("That is equal to " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
 }
} // end class
```